# Using avconv, when remuxing to MKV, is there a way to fix packed AVI input files?

Tags: video, avconv, mkv, transcode, avi

Due to compatibility bugs between Plex server and Panasonic TVs, the only way to get it to work well is remux everything to MKV, straight copy all streams (video, audio, subtitle)

Seems simple enough:

```
avconv -i "input.avi" -c copy "output.mkv"
```

Except:

```
avconv version 0.8.6-4:0.8.6-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Apr  2 2013 17:00:59 with gcc 4.6.3
[mpeg4 @ 0x8422140] Invalid and inefficient vfw-avi packed B frames detected
Input #0, avi, from 'input.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : VirtualDubMod 1.5.4.1 (build 2117/release)
  Duration: 00:27:38.52, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1173 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4 (Advanced Simple Profile), yuv420p, 640x352 [PAR 1:1 DAR 20:11], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 132 kb/s
File 'output.mkv' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, matroska, to 'output.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf53.21.1
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 640x352 [PAR 1:1 DAR 20:11], q=2-31, 1k tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: libmp3lame, 48000 Hz, stereo, 132 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
[matroska @ 0x8422cc0] Can't write packet with unknown timestamp
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
```

With the relevant gotcha lines being:

```
[mpeg4 @ 0x8422140] Invalid and inefficient vfw-avi packed B frames detected#
<snip>
[matroska @ 0x8422cc0] Can't write packet with unknown timestamp
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
```

I can't see an option to unpack the B frames (or build a VBR timemap? do we need those in avconv?)

Is there a way to do this, like in avidemux?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A workaround is to convert to .mp4 first:

```
avconv -i input.avi -c copy temp.mp4
avconv -i temp.mp4 -c copy output.mkv
rm temp.mp4
```

Sadly, one cannot simply pipe the mp4 format between avconv instances: "[mp4 @ 0x80846c0] muxer does not support non seekable output"

Comment: Thanks, I shall try it out this evening.
I wonder if there is a command that acts like a buffer? Waits for the command writing to stdin to complete before passing it all to stdout. With seek on stdout. That would be handy. `avconv -i xxx | buf | avconv -i stdin xxx`

Comment: The error message I appended is specifically related to trying to use pipes with avconv, as pipes are inherently non-seekable. The best one can do is to locate temp.mp4 on a tmpfs or similar in-memory filesystem. /dev/shm/ is a good candidate for this, if one has enough RAM.

Comment: Regarding piping, you can probably do it with named pipes aka fifo. Have a search for `mkfifo`. Essentially, you use a file as a temporary storage for stout.

Comment: This solution works also for ffmpeg

Answer (score 8):

As of [this ticket #1979 at ffmpeg bugtracker](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1979) the simplest solution is to have this bug fixed or to manually add `-fflags +genpts` to the command line.

I.e. change

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile_that_cant_be_muxed_into_mkv.ext -c copy out.mkv
```

to

```
ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -i inputfile_that_cant_be_muxed_into_mkv.ext -c copy out.mkv
```

Comment: This still gives me the same error :/

Comment: works for me with `avconv` version 0.8.16, until it displayed an odd `Can't write packet with unknown timestamp` at the end of the file. Weird.

Comment: Make sure `-fflags` is used as an input option: it has to go before your `-i input`.  But probably it wouldn't have worked at all if you hadn't put `+genpts` in the right place.

Comment: This works fine with `avconv` 9.18-6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 as well

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Andreas Cadhalpun `ffmpeg` now has new filter: `mpeg4_unpack_bframes` (see [ref](https://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commitdiff;h=0224b35c89e9e75f156962c93b37adab75d8df6a)). This will allow you to get rid of the message: `Invalid and inefficient vfw-avi packed B frames detected`.

Usage is as simple as:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT.avi -codec copy -bsf:v mpeg4_unpack_bframes OUTPUT.avi
```